# fetch data from database in random order with ajax without duplicate entry

Tags: php, mysql

I am working the listing site and i am fetching data from database in the chunks of 15 to 20 entries via ajax. but i am getting duplicate entries because of fetching data in random order.

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: i simply create a php file which is fetching 15 to 20 entries in each ajax call and with that i pass a comma separated ids to that file so that duplicate entries not be fetched. but now the data is getting bulkier and we can't pass that much id's in comma separated string.

Answer (score 0):

please try this `SELECT name FROM random ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;`

for more info visit : http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Comment: i already used this but the issue is that the data is fetched by ajax when scroll hits the footer and every time it randomly fetch the 15 to 20 ids and return to the ajax request and i cannot make the offset to the query because it is fatched in random order